# AV Foundation Capture Image

Tags: ios, objective-c

My basic task is to capture a part of an image and then use it. To give you an overview, I am creating an app based on OCR, I allow to user to take a picture using camera. However, rather than processing the entire image, I only want some part of it to be selected and send for processing (Preferably a rectangle). So, to sum it up, I want an overlay to be provided, and I want the image inside that overlay to be further used rather than the entire clicked image.

Now, by my understanding, I realize that AVFoundation is the tool to capture the image, however in my app I have used `UIImagePicker`. I am totally confused since I am a newbie and not sure hot to proceed ahead. Appreciate all for the help. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is fine open source library for OCR in iOS :

```
https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo
```

This will work best if the image resolution is 150 * 150 .  For more in formation of other libraries you can also refer the SO question:[OCR Lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062755/ocroptical-character-recoginition-libraries-for-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not what i am looking for, I already have a ready working ocr app, but to improve the accuracy, I want to provide a small rect. box for the user to chose exactly what area he wants to provide the OCR on. I am stuck in this step.